# DW service screen showing Nvidia logo

Tags: nvidia-jetson, screensharing

I installed DW service on Nvidia Jetson Orin Nano as a screen sharing alternative. When I select the “screen” option it is not going past the Nvidia logo and there are 0 fps. But I can access cmd and file sharing options. So device is connected and is active.

We tried to access the device via different locations as the device was working fine at the place of setup.